# Raspberry Pi Crashes when I try to change screen resolution

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, screen

I am running Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 3 and have been trying to change my screen resolution (connected to some Samsung touchscreen via HDMI) via

```
sudo raspi-config
```

the menu loads properly and I can change the settings except when I try to change screen resolution at which point the whole OS stops working. Any ideas?

edit:

it doesn't allow me to go into the menu which shows the options of what resolution to choose.

edit2:

Its not that I want to change it to a particular resolution, its that if I try to open that menu in raspi-config, the whole OS crashes and I have to restart the Pi

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: 5V 2A strongtonics. why?

Comment: Change from what old value to what new value? Not all are possible, please add these details to your question.

Comment: Recommended psu is the official 5.1V 2.5A 18AWG cable psu - might be a power glitch when changing mode?

Comment: would that prevent me from opening even the menu to try it out? Will try thanks!

Comment: Power supply was an issue for me on the Raspberry Pi 4 - went from a 1A to 2A power supply and that stopped the crashing when trying to change resolution. I will be looking for a beefier power supply to avoid future power-related crashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an older question now, but I was having this exact same issue with my Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

I found out that the issue for me was caused by having GL Driver set to "Full KMS".

Once I set it to "Fake KMS" I stopped having freezing problems.

1. In terminal type "sudo raspi-config"
2. Go to "Advanced Options"
3. Go to "GL Driver"
4. Select "G2 GL (Fake KMS)"
5. Reboot Pi

I hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: thanks! Solution confirmed on my Pi 3B+. I could change the resolution after changing to [Fake KMS]. No more hangs!

Comment: confirmed on PI 4B

Comment: After step 4 “Select G2 GL (Fake KMS)”, I needed to immediately go back to Advanced Options > Resolution and select my preferred resolution, because restarting between reverted to the standard GL selection.

Comment: This fixed my issue that occurred whenever screen blanking happened. If the screen blanked due to no input, the entire device would hard lockup forcing a manual power cycle. Thank you!